# How to increase width of child element beyond parent element

Tags: html, css, width, parent-child

I am trying to get something like [this blog](https://www.mybloggertricks.com/) which has:

[image]

But what I get is

[image]

(I am not trying to copy him, obviously I will change the image, etc.)

The borders are getting cut, because the width of the parent container (sidebar) is less than the width of the image. I google a lot, but all I found is `overflow:visible`, which somehow is still not working. Here is the [output](https://ilovetrollstestbeta.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two easy steps :

1. Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.sidebar .widget`.
2. Add negative margin on the both sides of `.sidebar h2` to make up for the width difference.

Comment: Actually i had done ctrl+f and put overflow:visible everywhere and removed overflow:hidden in .sidebar,so .siderbar.widget got left out..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a negative value to the margin of the desired element (for example, `{margin-left: -20px }`).

Don't forget to remove the overflow property from the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

**As per your question's requirement**: you could apply the margin value negatively, for example `margin-left: 15px;` and give `position: relative;` and you may need to define your style `float: left;` too.

**But alternatively,** you could define your parent element greater than your contents, for example, your contents is 200 pixels wide and your left and right image is 15 pixels + 15 pixels = 30 pixels, then your parent element should be 230 pixels wide and now arrange your elements by giving the floating value to the left for all three images and define the contents width now to 200 pixels and center it giving `margin: 0 auto;` to accomplish your work.